# Looking for a Dijit Widget which works like a default html select

Tags: javascript, dojo

I'm looking for a dijit widget which works like a normal html select (combobox).
all dijit widgets i found until now, have an editable text box.
I prefer to have a drop down box only and no editable textbox.

```
<select name="aCombobox">
    <option value="1" selected="selected">Hund</option>
    <option value="2">Katze</option>
    <option value="3">Maus</option>
    <option value="4">Waldelfe</option>
</select>
```

Also important for me is, that the upper code is working with the widget and the widget have to use the "Value" values and not the display text.

I checked this dijit widgets: combobutton, combobox, filteringselect, dropdownbutton.

Maybe there is an attribute i forgot to set.

Is there a widget which meet my requirements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to use dijit.form.FilteringSelect:

```
 <select name="aCombobox" dojotype="dijit.form.FilteringSelect">
     <option value="1" selected="selected">Hund</option>
     <option value="2">Katze</option>
     <option value="3">Maus</option>
     <option value="4">Waldelfe</option>
     <script type="dojo/connect" event="onChange">
       console.log( 'picked ' + this.attr('value') + 
                    ' = ' + this.attr('displayedValue') );
     </script>
 </select>
```

Hope this helps.

If you are feeling adventurous, you can try out dijit.form.DropDownSelect. It just got added on 7/21 to trunk.  [Here's the test.](http://archive.dojotoolkit.org/nightly/dojotoolkit/dijit/tests/form/test_DropDownSelect.html)

Comment: i tried that, it has also a editable edit. maybe I'm wrong - i will try it again on Monday.

Comment: What do you mean by 'editable edit'?  Do you mean a textinput?

Comment: in front of the drop down button is a editbox. i don't want that somebody can enter text there. that "select" have to work in the default windows way without any extension like filtering or selecting by typing.

Comment: Ah, gotcha.  Why not just use a plain vanilla select then.  Seems like you don't need a dijit for this.

Comment: i'm using dijit because our webdesigner can put his own design on it. on plain html he cant. the inputs depending to much on browser and OS.

Comment: Ok, updated my answer.  Otherwise, I think you'll need to create your own sublcass.

Answer (score 0):

I'm new so can't leave comments yet, but seth mentions dijit.form.DropDownSelect being in trunk - this is for 1.4 I believe; 1.3 has it in dojox as [dojox.form.DropDownSelect](http://docs.dojocampus.org/dojox/form/DropDownSelect)

Comment: @Bernd - thanks, but I was specifically pointing out that in 1.3 it is in dojox, not dijit.

Answer (score 0):

**[dijit.form.Select](http://api.dojotoolkit.org/jsdoc/HEAD/dijit.form.Select)** is what you need. It's in the latest builds and will be in 1.4. You can currently download it as part of the development release. The [test page](http://archive.dojotoolkit.org/nightly/dojotoolkit/dijit/tests/form/test_Select.html) has a bunch of demos.

It looks as if this replaces the dijit.form.DropDownSelect that seth mentioned.

We had the same problem about 6 months ago. We ended up using FilteringSelects, which was ugly. Nice to see that the Dojo people have finally made a proper select list.